# Magento setup script isn't running

Tags: magento

I'm using Magneto 1.7 with the cache disabled and my module enabled.

[image: magento setup script isn't running]
*View the image directly for a clear view.*

And this is after deleting the module's row from `core_resource`.

[image: magento deleting module row]

What should happen, is this displaying when I refresh the page.

> Running This Upgrade:
>   Magentotutorial_Weblog_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup Exit for now

Instead the script doesn't load, as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The screenshot is very hard to read. Please post your `etc/config.xml`, especially the `<config><modules><Desbest_Showdown><version>` node. And please post your `Desbest_Showdown_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup` class, too.

Comment: My config.xml is here https://gist.github.com/102c7ca470c175b50570 My Setup.php is here. https://gist.github.com/24b8f850b9a1ffef2c0d Yes it is version 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try renaming your `Showdown_setup` to `showdown_setup` (all lower case).
The next thing is that your setup file is called `mysql4-install-1.php`. This looks strange to me. What is the version you defined in your `config.xml`? Is it `<version>1</version>`? Because it must match the number in the install file name.
Also you should define `<models>` in your `config.xml` like this:

```
<global>
   <models>
      <showdown>
         <class>Desbest_Showdown_Model</class>
      </showdown>
   </models>
</global>
```

Comment: Yes it is version 1. You can see my config.xml here. https://gist.github.com/102c7ca470c175b50570 Renaming `sql/Showdown_setup` to lowercase doesn't work.

Comment: Another problem could be that you use your own setup class without defining models in your config.xml. See my changes in answer above.